# speckle interferometry (or other interferometry) software

Tags: software

This might not be the best place to ask, and if its not could someone please point me to where would be better, but here we go anyway.

Does anyone out there know of open source software which can be used for speckle interferometry with normal digital cameras? While speckle seams to be the standard, im happy to use other systems as well, but don't have easy access to lasers etc. It is to measure stress/strain curves of 15x15mm orthotropic samples but I don't need the strain fields within the samples so something less precise than speckle may well be appropriate.

Thanks for any ideas